Help with calling multicall contract via golang
I have the correct address and exact bytes but my result is always an empty byte split
I'm using a custom multicall where the function is a view function and the expected data returned is of the same format as multicall3 (from remix)
"0": "tuple(bool,bytes)[]: true,0x000000000000000000000000a01f675b2839e4104ca5deab898e49ffa4a8f7d3"

func PackedViewFunction(client ethclient.Client, contractAddress common.Address, packedData []byte) ([]byte, error) {
callMsg := ethereum.CallMsg{To: &contractAddress, Data: packedData}
result, err := client.CallContract(context.Background(), callMsg, nil)
if err != nil {
return nil, err
}
return result, nil
}


Turns out it was returning nothing because the address input is case sensitive for common.HexToAddress

type AggregateCall3 struct {
    Target       common.Address
    AllowFailure bool
    CallData     []byte
}

type Aggregate3Result struct {
    Success    bool
    ReturnData []byte
}

func Aggregate3Read(client *ethclient.Client, calls []AggregateCall3) (results []Aggregate3Result) {

    multicall3Abi, err := abi.JSON(strings.NewReader(multicall3.Multicall3ABI))
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }

    calldata, err := multicall3Abi.Pack("aggregate3", calls)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to pack data:", err)
        return nil
    }

    result, err := client.CallContract(context.Background(), ethereum.CallMsg{
        To:   &config.Multicall3Address,
        Data: calldata,
    }, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to call contract:", err)
        return nil

    }

    parsedResult, err := multicall3Abi.Unpack("aggregate3", result)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to unpack result:", err)
        return nil
    }

    for _, v := range parsedResult {
        // fmt.Printf("%T\n", v)

        for _, vv := range v.([]struct {
            Success    bool    "json:\"success\""
            ReturnData []uint8 "json:\"returnData\""
        }) {
            results = append(results, Aggregate3Result{
                Success:    vv.Success,
                ReturnData: vv.ReturnData,
            })
        }
    }

    return results
}

https://github.com/EthanOK/ethereum-dev/blob/main/utils/getMulticall.go#L88
https://github.com/EthanOK/ethereum-dev/blob/main/test/testMulticall3.go#L45
